# Is it possible to filter a frequency?

Tags: amplifier, frequency, active-filter, band-pass

I have built and tested an active band pass filter, with the intention of creating a speed detector, whose lower and upper cut off frequencies are 48 Hz and 1591 Hz respectively. During testing I confirmed attenuation of voltages out-with the bandwidth above and subsequent amplification. This was using a signal generator where of course, I could send the desired frequency through the circuit.

When I began using the radar module, transmitted frequency is 24 GHz (https://shop.bb-sensors.com/out/media/Datasheet_RADAR-IPM-165_DBE_Rev01.pdf), the received frequency was around 80 MHz and of course, voltage at this range even after amplification was extremely small.

Is there any way I can control the received frequency so I can analyse the frequency? If this isn't something that is possible, is there any other way I can analyse the received frequency?

I'm completely running out of ideas and thought this almost feels like last chance saloon.

I've added pictures of the circuit, radar input and circuit input and signal generator input and output.

As can be seen from the circuit diagram below, the radar is the input to the entire circuit. Both oscilloscope images display inputs and outputs. The outputs appear to be similar when a very large frequency is applied to the circuit, much larger than that of the upper cut off frequency.

[image: Circuit layout]

[image: Radar output and output of entire circuit]

[image: Signal generator input and output of entire circuit]

Comment: It sounds like you're putting a very high frequency into a low-pass filter, which attenuates it... If you're trying to detect doppler shift from the radar module, seems like something is missing from the system, don't you need a mixer to bring down the 24GHz carrier to baseband? Maybe a direct conversion or superheterodyne receiver?

Comment: @MarkU the module incorporates a mixer as far as I know, from reading the data sheet I wasn’t expecting to have to do much else other than amplify and cut off unwanted frequencies but it’s caused a lot more issues than expected

Comment: Take a look at this application note:
https://www.innosent.de/fileadmin/media/dokumente/Downloads/Application_Note_III_-_web.pdf

Comment: Also this might shed some light?
https://www.limpkin.fr/index.php?post/2017/02/22/Making-the-Electronics-for-a-24GHz-Doppler-Motion-Sensor

Comment: @MrGerber I’ve looked at both extensively, I built the circuit in the application note initially, with no luck. I’ve been using the Limpkin page as a reference quite frequently also but haven’t been able to find the solution to this current problem within it

Comment: Impossible for me to know, since it was not mentioned in the text. Anyway. Then it was not of any help. Is your question about how to excite the sensor to see different outputs?

Comment: @MrGerber essentially yes, the output doesn’t seem to be very consistent at all. This makes it extremely hard to analyse as you can imagine. Moving objects in front of the sensor doesn’t seem to have a consistent effect either

Comment: Are you sure you are moving the objects fast enough? Have you tried replicating the limpkin experiment video to exact details?

Comment: @MrGerber according to the data sheet, a 44Hz shift corresponds to approx 1 km/hr, which isn’t that fast at all so I don’t imagine it’s that. I’ve even bought another sensor in the off chance it was broken but the same output is observed. The only difference potentially is he uses a confined hallway which is something I could try I suppose

Comment: @Jandy12 Where did you get the idea that you are receiving 80 MHz? I didn't see that mentioned on the datasheet or on the whitepaper. What I did see is that there is a very large, but unknown and different for each unit, offset voltage with a very tiny added signal frequency riding on that. They recommended a small DC gain to start followed by AC coupling and more gain afterwards. And you aren't seriously using 741's are you?

Comment: @jonk the 80 MHz I’ve measured using an oscilloscope. “What I did see is that there is a very large, but unknown and different for each unit, offset voltage with a very tiny added signal frequency riding on that” what do you mean by this? I was planning on using 741’s but I do have the MC33078P op amp mentioned in the application note just didn’t have much luck with them before. Anything you can recommend?

Comment: @Jandy12 (1) Your scope says 40MHz on it. What do you think that means? (2) The limpkin site discusses opamps with only 1MHz gain bandwidth. Did you notice? (3) Either the short moments I spent reading weren't enough, or else I don't see a design that follows what I read as good advice in that whitepaper. So I think one of us has a reading problem. I'm willing to grant it is me. Perhaps someone else will point out the obvious. I'm too tired tonight to retrace my steps. But I do believe their product is good.

Comment: I see a a 90 Hz  sine wave with spikes and possible sampling errors, noise but I don’t see a block diagram and clear question showing a block diagram. Which part of the application note Do you not understand

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 if I’m honest none of it is making any sense now, but in particular is the part regarding the DC coupled amplifier stage, decoupling and then AC coupling immediately after. As well as that, I’m struggling to see how I can achieve any meaningful output that can be analysed when the signal looks as it does in the first oscilloscope picture. I’m going to change the op amps in the hope they’re contributing to the noise level but aside from that I’m at a loss as to what to do next

Comment: Be sure your layout is not introducing noise and your experiment is valid. I cannot advise you without a lot more details on the overall design

Comment: An ideal filter matches your expected spectral density.  Datasheet suggests 20~900Hz to amplify 300uV but you show 48 ~1591 Hz for no reason.  Care to define your filter specs better?

Comment: The data sheet suggests 20-900 bandwidth while others suggest 6-600 Hz, see MrGerbers first link. Purely based on the application circuit it seems. I chose 48-1591 Hz for no real specific reason, other than the lower would block out stationary objects (due to 44Hz relating to 1km/hr) and the upper would encapsulate faster moving objects.

Comment: @Jandy12 The DC amplification comment they made is because they say the offset voltage might be near \$200\:\text{mV}\$ (in fact, they say you can use this fact to detect that it is ON) and that their signal will ride on that as much as \$300\:\mu\text{V}\$. We're talking 1000:1 here, ignoring noise issues. They are suggesting that you *first* do a simple DC gain of about 10 or so (which will amplify both the offset and the signal from \$200\:\text{mV}\pm 300\:\mu\text{V}\$ to \$2\:\text{V}\pm 3\:\text{mV}\$) before applying a blocking capacitor. The signal will be \$3\:\text{mV}\$ by then.

Comment: Thanks jonk that makes sense. Appreciate all the help from everyone

Answer (score 1):

Any filter can be designed in theory to any practical specifications.

**No filter can be designed with inadequate specifications.**

A filter must not distort the signal amplitude in the passband (PB) with gain
But must also attenuate noise in the stopband (SB).

**Thus a minimum of 5 parameters are needed for a LPF.**

A full answer is not possible, because you MUST define signal spectral density ( f vs amplitude )and noise spectral density or amplitude an PW50 ( 50% pulse width ). An optimal filter may be selected by matching filter response to signal response and inverse of noise response.

There may be other specs from group delay.

```
Hypothetical             Spec 
======================== ==========
Av (gain)                1000  2%
Ripple (dB)  in PB gain  0.5dB max 
BWp of PB (Hz)           1591 Hz
BWs of SB (Hz)           5000 Hz  ( knowing SB/PS = -6dB/oct per order)    
SB rejection at BWs (dB) -60dB
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see in the pictures that you have a lot of high frequency noise coming from radar output to the OA input.

It's true that overall the HF attenuation might be correct but at the U1 output the noise is still amplified. Over 0.5V noise with 30x U1 gain will lead to over 15V  at U1 output making U1 and U2 working in non linear region.

Of course, if the frequency is high the noise will be filtered by R4 and C2 at the output but no LF small signal will survive.

MrGerber's app note shows two capacitors added in parallel with the feedback resistors (R3 and R6 in your schematic) to early filter the HF noise. In your case the capacitor value should be ~4.7nF for 600Hz (human move) or lower for higher object speed.

Comment: Thanks for your help thats made a bit of sense to me. So, you're suggesting a capacitor in parallel with the feedback resistor at each stage, while the rest of the circuit should remain the same? Or using the capacitor in parallel with the feedback resistor and removing the low pass filter that's after the output of U2?

Comment: The output filter has a cutoff  frequency of 1.5 khz, it makes no difference, let-it there until you figure out what happens. Later you can remove-it. The cutoff frequency for OA filters with 4.7nF capacitors is more like 1khz than 600 Hz. Everything else is good as is.